# Dijit DateTextArea Behaviour

Tags: dojo

I am using the dijit dateTextArea and am experiencing some odd behaviour. 
I have a simple form with the Dijit dateTextArea. I am setting a default value for the date and it appears fine. If I click into the date area, select a date and hit submit the date is picked up on the other side fine(i.e. it is submitted). If however I don't touch the dateTextArea (i.e. i don't click into it or give it any focus) and submit the form the date is blank, even though the default date has been set. I've tried setting the default date by setting the value on the widget, the initial value and by using data-dojo-props. The date displays in the field but unless I interact with the field the date does not get submitted.

So, what am I doing wrong? Does the field need focus at some point to work properly?
Is there an extra setting I should be using when specifying a default date?

Thanks

Comment: eh... substitute dateTextBox for dateTextArea... sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to tell what's wrong without seeing some code, but you shouldn't have to focus the input or anything for the value to be submitted.

If you look at the "Net" tab in firebug, is the date value part of the request when you submit the form?

I wasn't able to reproduce the problem in jsfiddle.. http://fiddle.jshell.net/DqHxL/ .

Comment: Hi,  thanks for the reply. I think I've found the issue. When I click on the field a hidden input field gets updated. Without clicking on the field the hidden input field does not get set properly. The hidden input field is part of the Dijit widget. Do I need to set this explicitly???

Comment: @fatlog You shouldn't need to do that, no. What dojo version are you using?

Comment: Hi Frode, Sorry about the long delay in replying to this. I am using a customised version of of the Dojo widgets called OneUI (IBM...). The problem seems to be in their extension

Answer (score 0):

How are you referencing the widgit? Is it with dijit.byId or document.getElementById. If you are using dijits you must use dijit.byId not getElement... Dojo creates shadow objects for everything